# Do I have to make up salat when I didn't know how to do it?

Tags: salat-qada

I converted to Islam seven months ago, and have been struggling to perfect salah. Do I have to make up all the prayers I missed from last May, even though I didn't know how to do it? There definitely was some laziness/carelessness involved, or I would have mastered it sooner. What should I do!?

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu alaikum wrwb there,

Welcome to Islam. No In Shaa Allah, you don't have to repeat what you have missed in the past, All you have to do is ask for forgiveness from Allah, repent and don't repeat it again. Islamic Online University has a special diploma courses designed for new muslims to learn all the basics including salah. So please check that out. Here is the link: https://www.islamiconlineuniversity.com/diploma/